# Finding the midpoint of the combinations of an array

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, iterator, rust, combinations

I have a struct which implements `Iterator` in Rust (though the question could apply to any language) to compute combinations of an array. The iterator is created with an initial array which defines the maximum value of each entry in the array. The actual code of the iterator is still a work in progress, so there's likely many places that could be improved.

For example, if I create a `Combo` using the `Combo::new()` function, and I give the `set_max` array, `[4,3,2,1]`, then the iterator will produce all the combinations of an array of length 4, such that no entry exceeds the entry given in `set_max`.

Thus, the first array that gets produced is `[0,0,0,1]`, followed by `[0,0,1,0]`, `[0,0,1,1]`, `[0,0,2,0]`, `[0,0,2,1]`, `[0,1,0,0]`, etc. Essentially, it increments a single entry at a time, until the entry is maxed-out. Then it resets it and begins incrementing two entries at a time.

I would like this iterator to implement `rayon::ParallelIterator` at some point, but first, I believe I need a way to split the computation of the combinations in half.

How do I find the halfway point of the iterator, so that I could split it into two pieces?

After I found this midpoint, I have some ideas on implementing the split function: adding a set_min array that specifies a starting point from which to being incrementing the entries. But the main point of the question is how to find the midpoint in general.

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Combos {
    pub set_max: Vec<usize>,
    set_current: Vec<usize>,
    size: usize,
}

impl Combos {
    pub fn new(set_max: Vec<usize>) -> Combos {
        Combos {
            set_current: vec![0; set_max.len()],
            size: set_max.iter().fold(1, |acc, x| (x + 1) * acc) - 1,
            set_max: set_max,
        }
    }

    fn increment_combo(&self, length: usize, combo: &[usize]) -> Vec<usize> {
        if let Some(last) = combo.last() {
            if *last == self.set_max[length - 1] {
                let mut v = self.increment_combo(length - 1, &combo[..length - 1]);
                v.push(0);
                return v
            } else {
                let mut v = combo.to_vec();
                v[length - 1] = last + 1;
                return v
            }
        } else {
            return Vec::new()
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Combos {
    type Item=Vec<usize>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Vec<usize>> {
        if self.set_current == self.set_max {
            return None
        }

        self.set_current = self.increment_combo(self.set_max.len(), &self.set_current);
        return Some(self.set_current.clone())
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting to create two iterators on the same `Combo` ?

Comment: This is more a mathematical problem than programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just half the first value of the array to cut the operation in half, since the first value is the last to be incremented in your algorithm (the most significant):

```
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

can be cut this way:

```
first part:  [0, 3, 2, 1] -> [1, 3, 2, 1]
second part: [2, 3, 2, 1] -> [3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Therefore, this is very easy to cut in half your algorithm: call the first part with `[2, 3, 2, 1]` and the second with `[4, 3, 2, 1]` with this beginning: `[2, 0, 0, 0]`.